# Applying technical trading rule to all combination of inputs

Tags: r, function, apply, rule, trading

I have a Dataframe with columns containing different time series of data. I need to insert these columns into the function below automatically to find the best combination (highest return):

```
returns <- as.data.frame(rep(0, 4261)) #4261 because that's the length of n1.lc
returns$n2_5_10 <- rep(0, nrow(returns))
MSVrule <- function(n1, n2, hold){
  for(i in 13:nrow(n1.lc)){
    if (n1[i] > n2[i] & n1[i-1] < n2[i-1]) {
      returns$n2_5_10[i] <- dt.lc$Settle[i - hold] - dt.lc$Settle[i]
    } else {
      if (n1[i] < n2[i] & n1[i-1] > n2[i-1])
      {returns$n2_5_10[i] <- dt.lc$Settle[i] - dt.lc$Settle[i - hold]
      }
      else{
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
}

MSVrule(n1.lc$N1_2_5, n2.lc$n2_2_10, 5)
```

This function doesn't work, leaving `returns$n2_5_10[i] 0` However, when I specifiy the vectors in the function it works:

```
hold <- 5
for(i in 13:nrow(n1.lc)){
    if (n1.lc$N1_2_5[i] > n2.lc$n2_2_10[i] & n1.lc$N1_2_5[i-1] < n2.lc$n2_2_10[i-1]) {
      returns$n2_5_10[i] <- (dt.lc$Settle[i - hold] - dt.lc$Settle[i]) / dt.lc$Settle[i]
    } else {
      if (n1.lc$N1_2_5[i] < n2.lc$n2_2_10[i] & n1.lc$N1_2_5[i-1] > n2.lc$n2_2_10[i-1])
      {returns$n2_5_10[i] <- (dt.lc$Settle[i] - dt.lc$Settle[i - hold]) / dt.lc$Settle[i - hold]
      }
      else{
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
```

The next step would be to automatically apply the function to other combinations of vectors from the `n1.lc` Dataframe. But I need the function to work first.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Right now you don't say what the error is, can you expand on this?

Comment: Both sample codes are not equivalent operations as bottom has divisors in `if` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use a function with no `return()` attempting to modify objects outside its scope, nothing external will be changed. However, you can use `<<-` operator to modify external objects to the function, namely the *n2_5_10* column in *returns*:

Below demonstrates with random generated data and assigns the column in returns with 500 or 5 as you do not post other needed, used objects (i.e., *dt.lc*). Adjust to actual data objects:

```
n1.lc <- data.frame(
             N1_2_5 = runif(50),
             n2_2_10 = runif(50)
         )

returns <- data.frame(n2_5_10 = rep(0, nrow(n1.lc)))

MSVrule <- function(n1, n2, hold){
  for(i in 13:nrow(n1.lc)){
    if (n1[i] > n2[i] & n1[i-1] < n2[i-1]) {
      returns$n2_5_10[i] <<- 500
    } else {
      if (n1[i] < n2[i] & n1[i-1] > n2[i-1])
      {returns$n2_5_10[i] <<- 5
      }
      else{
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
}

MSVrule(n1.lc$N1_2_5, n1.lc$n2_2_10, 5)
```

However, consider using `return` where you create/update/output *returns* inside function. Then on outside, assign a new dataframe as the function's output (no need for `else { NULL }` clause):

```
MSVrule <- function(n1, n2, hold){
  returns <- data.frame(n2_5_10 = rep(0, nrow(n1.lc)))

  for(i in 13:nrow(n1.lc)){
    if (n1[i] > n2[i] & n1[i-1] < n2[i-1]) {
      returns$n2_5_10[i] <- 500
    } else {
      if (n1[i] < n2[i] & n1[i-1] > n2[i-1])
        returns$n2_5_10[i] <- 5          
    }
  }

  return(returns)
}    

newdf <- MSVrule(n1.lc$N1_2_5, n1.lc$n2_2_10, 5) 


# BOTH ABOVE RESULT IN EQUIVALENT OUTCOMES
all.equal(returns, newdf)
# TRUE

identical(returns, newdf)
# TRUE
```